# Interest to publish a bot?

Tags: bots, botframework

I am beginning in the creation of bots with Microsoft Bot Framework.

What is the interest to publish a bot on the Microsoft portal?

Comment: Publishing the bot on Microsoft portal is not mandatory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing a bot is only required if you want your bot to appear in the [Bot Directory](https://bots.botframework.com/). You don't even need to register the bot until you want to test it in another channels or host somewhere.

[This](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/faq/#do-i-have-to-publish-my-bot-to-the-bot-directory-in-order-for-my-bot-to-be-available-to-users) entry in the FAQ talk about it.

[image]